# Is it safe to use Google Test's apparently-internal CaptureStdOut?

Tags: googletest

I've seen the following (useful) code on the net for capturing standard output for checking within Google Test:

```
testing::internal::CaptureStdout();
DoSomethingThatOutputsToStdout();
std::string result = testing::internal::GetCapturedStdout();
ASSERT_EQ(expectedString, result);
```

Now the only thing that concerns me is that this function is part of the `internal` namespace. The `gtest_internal.h` header file states explicitly:

> This header file declares functions and macros used internally by Google Test.  They are subject to change without notice.

However, the definition for `CaptueStdout` is not actually *in* that header file, instead residing in `gtest-port.cc`, a file that has no similar warning. But it *is* contained within the internal namespace.

Hence my question is whether or not it is considered okay to use that function despite the fact it appears to be in an internal namespace. I don't want to tie myself to something that the authors may decide to change at their whim.

Or is my understanding of the intent of the `internal` namespace flawed?

Comment: I think that your understanding is right - using the code from the `internal` namespace might cause issues as this functionality is not an official API of `gtest` and might be changed without any notice. 

When I was facing similar problem in the past I ended up injecting some kind of a `Logger` class what would log to the standard output in the real code and would be mocked/stubbed in the tests.